# $\int\limits_{0}^{32/9}\sqrt{1+\frac{9x}{4}}dx$

Tags: integration, roots, radicals

**Question** : Solve $\int\limits_{0}^{32/9}\sqrt{1+\frac{9x}{4}}dx$

**My Try:**  Let u = $1+\frac{9x}{4}$

Then,

$$du = \frac{9x}{4}dx$$

$$dx = \frac{4du}{9}$$

Substituting the above in the main equation, we get:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{32/9} \sqrt u \left(\frac{4du}{9}\right)$$

$$ \left. \left(\frac{4}{9}\right)\frac{2(u^{3/2})}{3}\right|_{0}^{\frac{32}{9}}$$

$$ \frac{4}{9} \frac{2\left(\left(1+\frac{9(32/9)}{4}\right)^{3/2}\right)}{3}$$

$$ \left(\frac{4}{9}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(9^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$

= 8

But the correct answer is 7.703...

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT :** Thank you all for your help. In case anyone else has this problem [this](http://www.tc3.edu/instruct/sbrown/calc/usubst.htm) website builds upon Oliver's answer.

Comment: When you introduced the new variable just change the limits according to it too, it makes calculation easier, resubstituting the older variable makes calculation more prone to error.

Comment: When $x=0$, $u$ is not zero. Where did it go?

Comment: That's what I do not understand, can any of you explain why the limits change?

Comment: Your work is mostly correct. You plugged in $u = 1 + 9/4(32/9)$ for when $x = 32/9$. But when you evaluate a definite integral you have to use BOTH endpoints- you also have to consider when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing the change of variable $\displaystyle u=1+\frac{9x}{4}$ gives
$$
u(0)=1,\quad u(32/9)=9,\quad du=\frac94dx,\quad dx=\frac49du,\quad 
$$ then you just get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{32/9}\sqrt{1+\frac{9x}{4}}dx&=\frac49\int_{1}^{9}\sqrt{u}\:du\\\\
&=\frac49\left[\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} \right]_1^9\\\\
&=\frac{8}{27}\left(9^{3/2}-1^{3/2} \right)\\\\
&=\frac{208}{27}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your clearly explained answer. I just watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJoyIAIC1Ag) about when to change the limits and when not to. He says that when you substitute the original value of u, which is 1+(9x)/2 , there is no need to change the limits. Hence, my solution should be correct shouldn't it?

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB I would say that when the integral is a *definite integral* (as above), then one may change the limits to finish the computation, when it is an *indefinite integral*, you don't have limits and it is usually better to come back to the initial variable. Thanks.